# Mysql Query takes more time if we call it two times first for Get count then for listing

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing problem related to mysql query.I need to get first calculate no. of records by different level and then showing it's listing for example:

```
select MAX(Orders) from priority where priority_type='Top_Priority';
select MAX(Orders) from priority where priority_type='Priority';
select MAX(Orders) from priority where priority_type='Regular';
```

- Top Priority (120 orders)
- Priority (100 orders)
- Regular (50 orders)

After that i am getting same record for listing like:

```
select * from priority where priority_type='Top_Priority';
select * from priority where priority_type='Priority';
select * from priority where priority_type='Regular';
```

It's take much time to execute. Is there is another way to do this which will improve execution performance.

Comment: Do you have indexes on ``Orders`` and ``priority_type``?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(column)` will return the [maximum value in `column`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-row.html), not the number of records. You want [`COUNT(column)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) for that.

Comment: The two queries don't return the same records. The first query just returns one record for each priority type, containing the max of the column. The second query returns all the records.

Comment: BTW, you can do the first query in a single query. `SELECT priority_type, MAX(Orders) FROM priority GROUP BY priority_type`

Comment: Only thing you have to do is `index` the `Orders` and `priority_type` column and it will speed up your execution time, and if you want to get total records then use `count` instead of `max`, `max` will return maximum number of orders of that specific type.

Comment: @ kmoser :Orders and priority_type columns already indexed.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, both queries return different records.Can we get both records in single query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the records with the max of for each type.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.OrderMax
FROM priority AS t1
JOIN (SELECT priority_type, MAX(Orders) AS OrderMax
      FROM priority
      GROUP BY priority_type) AS t2 ON t1.priority_ttpe = t2.priority_type
```

To speed up this query, it would be best if you have a multi-column index on `(priority_type, Orders)` in the table.